# npm install, can't type Y/n in cmd

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, command-line

I am trying to setup a `react-js` website, and when I do `npm install`, it asks me:

```
Building the Webpack DLL...
[webpack-cli] For using 'build' command you need to install: 'webpack' package.
[webpack-cli] Would you like to install 'webpack' package? (That will run 'npm install -D webpack') (Y/n)
```

The problem is, it is impossible to type anything. I tried cmd, powershell, git bash. It does not allow me to type. Why is this happening?

When I run the actual command `npm install -D webpack` it executes. But when I run `npm install` to continue installing, the same thing happens again, again asking me to type `Y/n` as if `webpack` wasn't installed already.

Comment: While it's not a direct answer, have you tried to use one of the tools like create-react-app?